# Dynamic list using ternary if are not accepted by apex

Tags: apex, trigger, compile-error

Considering the code snippet:

```
..
List<SObject> lstSObject = sentence == true ? List<typeA__c>() : List<typeB__c>();
```

Salesforce doesn't explain much as this operator should be straightforward.

And following the principle of the java operator too. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java

To confirm my thought, is the compiler verifying what is bidding on the interface (List) and considering its type itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not true, for the same SObject types, it works, you just forgot `new`:

```
List<SObject> lstSObject = (sentence ? new List<typeA__c>() : new List<typeA__c>());
```

And for different SObject types it works too, but you should do casting:

```
List<SObject> lstSObject = (sentence ? (List<SObject>) new List<typeA__c>() : (List<SObject>) new List<typeB__c>());
```

Comment: You're right @Mariia I've mistyped during the edition and hasn't added the cast internally from List<Object> thanks!

Comment: And the reason why the cast is necessary is because ternaries require that both possible results return the same type.